# mysql query results false output

Tags: php, mysql

Insert the row after deleting the row of child table when updating the data ,how to compare inserting

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ( stu_no,username,maths,english,telugu,id) VALUES 
      ('".$_POST['stu_no']."','".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['maths']."',
      '".$_POST['english']."',)'".$_POST['teslugu']."','".$_GET['id']."')";
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question to make it more understandable?

Comment: may be you need a trigger?

Comment: @David - You nay want to try putting your code in SQL Fiddle. It's and awesome site to mess with code.

Answer (score 2):

you missed table name, so do:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name_here (stu_no,username..
```

**Added:**

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ( stu_no,username,maths,english,telugu,id) VALUES 
      ('".$_POST['stu_no']."','".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['maths']."',
      '".$_POST['english']."','".$_POST['teslugu']."','".$_GET['id']."')");
```

Comment: i mention table name,but two times inserted rows

Comment: @david is your insert query inside some loop, else this exact query should only have inserted data once, as there's no such code that makes it insert twice...!

Comment: there's one parenthesis misplaced, so added correct statement. And if 'id' is your auto increment field, then you need not add it to your insert query..

Answer (score 0):

@Sudhir is right, you missed table name. Moreover, don't use $_POST values directly in mysql statements. You have to use,

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

One more thing, If you don't want to open and close double quotes many times then you can also format query string like,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`stu_no`,`username`,`maths`,`english`,`telugu`, `id`)
 VALUES ('{$_POST['stu_no']}','{$_POST['username']}','{$_POST['maths']}',
'{$_POST['english']}','{$_POST['telugu']}','{$_GET['id']}'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table ( `stu_no`,`username`,`maths`,`english`,`telugu`,`id`) VALUES 
  ('$_POST['stu_no']','$_POST['username']','$_POST['maths']',
  '$_POST['english']','$_POST['teslugu']','$_GET['id']')");
```